# Especificar versiones de Bundler en el Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

Un build de mi proyecto en TravisCI falló porque Travis decidió usar una versión de Bundler (1.6.9, creo) que no soporta bloques en el `source`, como este:

```ruby
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-urijs'
end
```

Sin hacer ningún otro cambio, re-lancé el build, y ahí Travis usó Bundler 1.11.2, que soporta ese feature, y todo funcionó bien.

Entonces, **¿cómo puedo especificar en mi proyecto la versión mínima de Bundler con la que quiero que trabaje?**

Creo haber visto proyectos que listan `bundler` como dependencia en su `Gemfile`, pero no estoy encontrando ninguna referencia ahora.

Answer (score 3):

Para comunicarle a Travis.ci que quieres usar una versión diferente de Bundler tienes que irte un paso antes del `Gemfile`, porque se presume que uno ya tiene `bundler` instalado cuando se tiene un `Gemfile`.

Por suerte con Travis.ci lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

En tu `.travis.yml` específica la siguiente línea:

```
before_install: gem install bundler -v 1.11.2
```

Ya está.

Referencia: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby#Custom-Bundler-arguments-and-Gemfile-locations

Comment: +1 por resolver el problema, aunque me gustaría una respuesta que sea independiente de _dónde_ esté buildeando el proyecto.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia no creo que consigas eso una solución multi-plataforma...